# how to know what page or call is being when in a JSP page when submited

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a JSP page called X.JSP (contains few radio button and submit button), when i hit the submit button in X.JSP, the next page is displayed Y.JSP?xxxx=1111&yyyy=2222&zzzz=3333

1. how to know what page or service or ajax call is being made when i hit the submit button in X.JSP page.
2. xxxx=1111&yyyy=2222&zzzz=3333 these are generated after i click the submit button in X.JSP

Currently i am using python to script.
i select a radio button and post the form. i am not able to get the desired O/P.
how do I what page or service or ajax call is being made when i hit the submit button in X.JSP page, so that i can directly hit that page
or is there any better way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The `developers console` ( <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome and Firefox) is a wonderful thing.

Check the Network or Net tab. There you can see all the requests between your browser and your server.

Comment: Yes.. i am able to see the the final page that it's redirecting to. 
the problem here is the the X.JSP page does some process intermediately and then displays the second page.

How do i how which script / page it calls first before it displays the results in a new form.?